# In OOP, how does persistence cooperate with object relations?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, persistence

So in OOP, objects send messages to other objects. This is a pretty simple concept, and as long as all of the objects live in memory, it's easy to implement e.g. by calling methods.

But in real life, we persist objects into the database or elsewhere, because there isn't enough RAM to hold all of them. How do you call a method on an object that is currently persisted?

OK, so maybe unpersisting *one* object can be incapsulated into its Factory. But what if I want to send messages to a lot of objects, e.g. in a loop? Unpersisting them one by one is a classic N+1 issue.

OK, I can have a Repository that'll unpersist all necessary objects in one shot. But doesn't it break incapsulation to ask a Repository to get my objects?

What about patterns like Observer? Is it possible to have an object subscribe to anything, knowing that it's going to be persisted?

Are there transparent implementations of this in any language?

Comment: I dont think that you can communicate with the object that get persisted.

Comment: Short answer: Check GemStone/S. For details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500984/build-system-that-is-not-file-centric/15594864#15594864

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does.  RAM is critical to OOP.  Once you persist something, outside of RAM, it's not OOP anymore.

An object is actually the total of all the objects it's in contact with, plus all the objects *they*'re in contact with, plus....  To work, an object needs almost instant communications with many other objects.  Without that, performance will lurch to a halt.  (Think virtual memory:  if you've ever used 1.5GB on a machine with 0.5GB, you'll know the problem.)

Storage based on slow memory tends to use either relational storage or big blocks of sequential data, each block accessed ramdomly by key.  I have written large-data, highly interactive (and so heavily OO) systems that persisted their data in a SQL database.  I had to organize the DB so it could be divided into managable blocks, each able to stand on its own, several of which would be loaded into a session.  Then I had to write vast amounts of code to turn the tables, rows, and columns into useful objects.  To write to the DB, I had to reverse the whole process.

So to start the program, the DB data went into a blender and came out something completely different.  When the user was done and saved to the database, the data got unblended and put back.  The in-memory objects had no obvious relationship with the DB tables (though obviously one could be created from the other with enough work).  And that's as close as I've been able to get to usable persistence.  The atomic units were much bigger than objects or rows, and each transformation took a while (whole seconds).

I've worked a (very) little bit with ORM.  The trick here is that OO is used to mimick relationals storage.  You end up not with the objects you'd get if you started with a good OO design, but with something that looks just like a relational database.  In a lot of cases this is just what you want and it works very well.  But it's not *real* OOP and probably is not what you're looking for.

So I've found no general answer.  Fast memory and OO--and slow memory and relational/non-realtional--are two different things, and bridging that gap takes careful study of specific cases and bit of genius.